# Batch File to move specifically named files from multiple subfolders into the parent folder

Tags: windows, batch

Been trying to figure this out for a while now, I'm trying to make a batch file that I can put in to any folder that will grab a file with specific text in the filename from all subfolders and put it in the parent folder.
In my current case:

---

```
Parent Folder (dynamic name)  
|Subfolder1 (dynamic name, date/time in my case)  
||potato1.jpg, cucumber1.jpg, banana1.jpg  

|Subfolder2 (dynamic name, date/time in my case)  
||potato2.jpg, cucumber2.jpg, banana2.jpg
```

---

I want a batch file to grab all of the **cucumber*.jpg** files and place them in the parent folder, not a specific path but whatever parent folder I drop the batch file in to. AND if possible have the subfolders deleted after.

So far I've got this:
FORFILES /s /c "cmd /c move *Screenshot* ."
PAUSE
But it seems to just "move" the files no where

As you can probably tell I'm not particularly experienced using batch script, I thought it would be relatively easy to do what I'm trying to do but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Might not be too hard if you use `forfiles`, and can be done in one line I think.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].